# Would Gordon Freeman have died after killing the Nihilanth?

Tags: half-life

At the end of *Half-Life 2* after the Teleporter is destroyed, when Alex is saying they have time (to escape the explosion i assume) Time freezes and G-Man appears interrupting Alex (now frozen as well) saying:

> Time, Dr. Freeman? Is it really that … time again? It seems as if you only just arrived.

the only thing that i can think of repeating here which would be *"that time again"* is when Gordon defeated the Nihilanth and he began to float up towards the Nihilanth and looked like it was about to explode.

From what i remember the Nihilanth was still much further off and if it was creating some sort of gravity disturbance and Gordon was just coincidentally starting to move closer to it, even if he had gotten up higher and gravity returned to normal (whatever that might be in Xen) he wouldn't have died from the fall because Gorden had to use the jumping pad things to get up high enough above the Nihilanth to to shoot it in it's opened up head and he landed back on the ground just fine after that

so if G-Man didn't show up would Gordon have been killed? or is G-Man making some other comparison

Comment: This is all clarified in Episode 3. Don't worry, it should be out any day now.

Answer (score 2):

You should play Half-Life 2, Episode 1: at the beginning we can see he is saved anyway by vortigaunts teleporting him before the citadel explosion.

Also when fighting the Nihilanth if I remember correctly the ground is fall-proof so if you miss a jump and fall all the way down, you will just land on the ground and have to jump your way again...

Comment: i've played Episodes 1 and 2 from what i recall the Vortigaunts save Alex from the Citadel while with Gordon they appear to stand between him and G-Man as if they are pulling Gordon out from that void he was left in at the end of the first game (Similar to what Adrian Shephard was left in). G-Man seems to imply in Episode 2 that they were getting in his way in contacting Gordon

Comment: You could argue that back in Half-Life immediately after Nihilanth's defeat they wouldn't recover their autonomy fast enough to save Gordon.